# returning 'null' in a webservice webmethod

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a simple webservice, playing around I found out that if I return `null` I get the following exception:

`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Method Parameter: return cannot be null. This is BP 1.1 R2211 violation. Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.`

Here is the sample code, is there a configuration which allows the webservice to return null values? 
Handling Strings is not a big problem, I would just return `""`.
 
How about returning a POJO? 
Reading from a database I would prefere returning `null` than having to create an empty POJO.

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface IShareObjectService {

    @WebMethod
    String getTest();
}


@WebService(endpointInterface = "ch.scodi.share.service.IShareObjectService", name = "ShareObjectService", serviceName = "ShareObjectService", targetNamespace = "http://shareserver/ws/")
public class ShareObjectService implements IShareObjectService {
    /** ShareObject data access object */
    private ShareObjectDAO dao;

    @Override
    public String getTest() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT --

Lets say I would like to do the following on the client:

```
Category category = categoryService.getByName(name);
if (category == null) {
    category = categoryService.create(name);
}
category...
```

Right now I would have to do something like this, needing an 'exists...' method for every 'get...' and 'find...' method which returns a single result.

```
Category category = null;
if (categoryService.existsByName(name)) {
    category = categoryService.getByName(name);
} else {
    category = categoryService.create(name);
}
category...
```

So I think I'm missing something?

Comment: *I would prefer returning null than having to create an empty POJO* And anyone using the webservice would prefer an empty POJO over null.

Comment: How about you have a method "User getUser(String userId)", wouldn't you expect null if no user is found for the userId instead of an empty User object?

Comment: I'd expect an error.

Comment: I added an example to explain the downside I see.

Comment: A further note, as a developer I would like to be abel to decide if I throw an exception or return null from a webmethod. 
If this is not possible because of a technical restriction, could someone point me to the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, I had to change the following annoation of my service interface from 
`@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)`
to
`@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)`.

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface IShareObjectService {

  @WebMethod
  String getTest();
}
```

More inforation about the binding styles can be found here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/